# How to redirect all the requests to check.php except of sample.com/index.html and sample.com/?i=1

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to redirect all the requests such as `example.com/123` or `example.com/any-url` to `check.php`. But I need to not redirect these two requests: `example.com/` and `example.com/?i=1`.

Here is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(|?i=1)($|/) - [L]
RewriteRule .* check.php
```

But this one still redirects everything to check.php What have I done wrong?

Comment: Do you explicitly need to redirect both `/` and `/index.html`? Should a URL such as `/?i=2` be redirected? Should this be an external redirect or an internal rewrite?

Comment: I need to redirect to check.php everything, except example.com, example.com/index.html and example.com/?i=1. There is no need to redirect URLs such as /?i=2

Comment: "There is _no need_ to redirect URLs such as /?i=2" - although you've not explicitly included this as one of the URLs to exclude, so right now this will be redirected, unless you wanted to exclude all `i=<anything>`?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(|?i=1)($|/) - [L]
> ```

You can't match the query string with the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. Only the URL-path (which notably excludes the query string) can be matched here, you need to use a `RewriteCond` directive to match the query string. (However, that regex looks invalid and I would have expected it to have generated a 500 error? That is, if it's being executed at all??)

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^i=1$
RewriteRule !^(index\.html)?$ check.php [L]
```

For all requests other than the document root (and `/index.html`) that do not contain the query string `i=1` then rewrite to `check.php`.

Note that this is an internal rewrite, as opposed to an external redirect.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Tried this one, but still if I try example.com or example.com/?=1 it redirects me to check.php. Should I screen question mark somehow?

Comment: "or example.com/?=1" - Presumably you mean "i=1"? By "redirect" do you mean you are physically redirected to `check.php` (ie. you see this in the address bar)? You might be seeing a cached redirect? Try clearing your browser cache. What is the DirectoryIndex? eg. Is `index.php` available? "Should I screen question mark somehow" - No, the question mark in the regex above makes the preceding group optional, it is not a _literal_ question mark.